# How to print multiple lines from a file python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print several lines from a text file onto python, where it is outputted. My current code is:

```
f = open("sample.txt", "r").readlines()[2 ,3]
print(f)
```

However i'm getting the error message of:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Is there anyway of fixing this or printing multiple lines from a file without printing them out individually?

Comment: You can't do `[2, 3]` at the same time.
Do `f = open("sample.txt", 'r').readlines(); print(f[2], f[3])`

Comment: You can do `...[2:4]` if you want list elements 2 and 3.

Comment: @JayPatel how would i do it?

Comment: @khelwood I don't understand?

Comment: @LoY4lFrost `lines = open("sample.txt", "r").readlines()[2:4]` will give you a list containing lines 2 and 3 of your file.

Comment: There is no such thing like `f[2, 3]`. It's either `f[2]` and `f[3]` or like @khelwood said `f[2:4]`

Comment: @khelwood ahh ok thanks, but that leaves it as a list, i'm trying to print solutions to a problem for a troubleshooter, so this wouldn't be exactly user friendly

Comment: Wait sorry @JayPatel I didn't see your solution before, but that works, Thanks :)

Comment: `f = open("example.txt", "r"); print("\n".join(f.readlines()[2:3+1])); f.close()` could work for you, see https://docs.python.org/index.html for Python documentation which will help and contains a tutorial as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a tuple to the `[...]` subscription operation; `2 ,3` is a tuple of two elements:

```
>>> 2 ,3
(2, 3)
```

You have a few options here:

- Use slicing to take a sublist from all the lines. `[2:4]` slices from the 3rd line and includes the 4th line:

  ```
  f = open("sample.txt", "r").readlines()[2:4]
  ```
- Store the lines and print specific indices, one by one:

  ```
  f = open("sample.txt", "r").readlines()
  print f[2].rstrip()
  print f[3].rstrip()
  ```

  I used `str.rstrip()` to remove the newline that's still part of the line before printing.
- Use `itertools.islice()` and use the file object as an iterable; this is the most efficient method as no lines need to be stored in memory for more than just the printing work:

  ```
  from itertools import islice

  with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
      for line in islice(f, 2, 4):
          print line.rstrip()
  ```

  I also used the file object as a context manager to ensure it is closed again properly once the `with` block is done.

Comment: This is printing only once what if want to use this with large file

Comment: @MansurAli: not sure what you are asking. `islice()` is perfectly suited for a large file.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the whole list of lines to a variable, and then print lines 2 and 3 separately.

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
print(lines[2])
print(lines[3])
```

Comment: This is exaclty what i'm trying to avoid, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: & Don't worry I got the answer from Jay Patel